# C# MVC List and Create in same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a model like this

```
public class Roles
{
     [Key]
     public string RoleId {get;set;}
     public string RoleName {get;set;}
}
```

The challenge I have with this is creating a single view for the List and create. Each attempt I have made ended up in data type error. What do I do?

Comment: why are you making viewmodels for simple views , use viewmodels for some complex operation only...just make one model for your view

Comment: Lol. All that I did in my confused state of mind

Comment: But how do I prevent `RoleId` from being displayed in my view while I'm using ` @Html.EditorForModel()` ?

Comment: @Peter..i think my answer is elaborate enough to make you understand..???

Comment: if you need more help then comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

In Order to hide some fields(as asked in Comments section) in `@Html.EditorForModel()` you have to use :

`[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` attribute

Ex :-

```
 [Key]
 [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
 public string RoleId {get;set;}
```

**Answer 2:**

and creating and showing list on the same view :

Model :

```
public class Roles
{
 [Key]
 public string RoleId {get;set;}
 public string RoleName {get;set;}
 public List<Roles> Roleslist { get;set; }  //Take a list in Model as shown
}
```

View :

```
 <div id="mainwrapper">

 @using (Html.BeginForm("// Action Name //", "// Controller Name //", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form1" }))
  {  

   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RoleName)
   <input type="submit" value="Save"/>

  }
  <div id="RolesList">
   @if(Model!=null)
    {
      if(Model.Roleslist!=null)
      {
       foreach(var item in Model.Roleslist) //Just Populate Roleslist with values on controller side
       {
       //here item will have your values of RoleId and RoleName 
       }
      }
    }
  </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Good one from you! Thanks.

Comment: Error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object on `foreach(var item in Model.Roleslist)` I thought I could handle it. What do you think ?

Comment: yes this error will come there should be something in Model.Roleslist to display

Comment: Even when I wrapped it within `if (Model.Roleslist != null ){` ?

Comment: just see my updated answer...just give it one more wrap as shown above

Answer (score 2):

Also check your controller to ensure you are not passing `Roles.ToList()` to the `CreateRole` view.
You can do this:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateRole()
    {
        var roles = from ur in db.roles
                    orderby ur.RoleName
                    select ur;
        ViewBag.Listroles = roles.ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

where `db` is your `DbContext`.

And your view should look like this:

```
  @{

      if(ViewBag.Listroles != null){
      foreach (var roles in ViewBag.Listroles)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>@roles.RoleName</td>
                <td>
                      @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditRoles", new { id=roles.RoleId }) |
                      @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=roles.RoleId }) |
                      @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=roles.RoleId })
                 </td>
            </tr>
        }

      }

    }
```

Let me know if my answer helps.